# Removing NA from Sankey Diagram (flipPlots Sankeydiagram)

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

I am currently struggling with a sankey diagram visualising the flow of anti-cancer treatment for women with advanced breast cancer.

I have a columnn for each line of treatment (beh1, beh2 etc) naming the given treatment (6 options or "Other").

However, some of the patients do not receive all 6 lines of treatment that my df currently contains, and have thus been give a N/A in several columns.

An example

```
sankey <- data.frame(ID = c("1","2","3","4","5"),
                 Beh1 = c("TDM1","Capecitabine", "Capecitabine", "Eribulin", "TDM1"),
                 Beh2 = c("Capecitabine", "NA", "Taxane", "Eksperimentiel", "Taxane"),
                 Beh3 = c("Eribulin", "NA", "Eribulin", "Eribulin", "Eribulin"))
```

And the diagram
[image]

```
    SankeyDiagram(sankey[-1],
          link.color = "Source",
          variables.share.values = TRUE,)
```

What I wished it showed:

[image]

Any help would be *highly* appreciated

Kind regards

Comment: Just a guess, try to recode string `"NA"` into a real `NA`: `sankey[ sankey == "NA" ] <- NA`

Comment: @zx8754 I'm using library(flipPlots) for the SankeyDiagram
And in my 'true' dataset they are 'real' NAs - I just tried your solution, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would convert your data.frame so that it contains factors instead of character columns and actual `NA` values instead of character `"NA"`s.

```
sankey <- data.frame(ID = c("1","2","3","4","5"),
                     Beh1 = c("TDM1","Capecitabine", "Capecitabine", "Eribulin", "TDM1"),
                     Beh2 = c("Capecitabine", NA, "Taxane", "Eksperimentiel", "Taxane"),
                     Beh3 = c("Eribulin", NA, "Eribulin", "Eribulin", "Eribulin"), 
                     stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

If you call `SankeyDiagram` with `output.data.only = TRUE` you get the nodes and links that the function uses to produce the diagram. You can then edit the links to exclude the link involving the NAs and call `SankeyDiagram` with the modified links. Adding `sinks.right = FALSE` to the `SankeyDiagram` call ensures that the second link for "Beh1: Capecitabine" doesn't extend to the right edge of the plot.

```
links.and.nodes <- SankeyDiagram(sankey[-1], link.color = "Source", output.data.only = TRUE, 
                                 variables.share.values = TRUE, sinks.right = FALSE)
links.and.nodes$links <- od$links[!is.na(od$links$group), ]
SankeyDiagram(links.and.nodes = links.and.nodes, link.color = "Source", 
              variables.share.values = TRUE, sinks.right = FALSE)
```

[SankeyDiagram output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HHhS.png)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! This was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```r
library(tidyverse)
# require(devtools)
# install_github("Displayr/flipPlots")

sankey <- data.frame(ID = c("1","2","3","4","5"),
                     Beh1 = c("TDM1","Capecitabine", "Capecitabine", "Eribulin", "TDM1"),
                     Beh2 = c("Capecitabine", "NA", "Taxane", "Eksperimentiel", "Taxane"),
                     Beh3 = c("Eribulin", "NA", "Eribulin", "Eribulin", "Eribulin"))

sankey %>%
  dplyr::na_if("NA") %>% 
  tidyr::drop_na() %>%
  dplyr::select(-1) %>% 
  SankeyDiagram(link.color = "Source",
              variables.share.values = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. 
Unfortunately this results in the diagram only showing those will complete data for all treatments.
It ought to still represent two patients receiving 'capecitabine' in the first row of nodes.

Comment: Yes, I figgered but I did not find a way with SankeyDiagram function and then I started to wonder what the point of that unconnected node really was.